# По какой причине возникает ошибка AttributeError подскажите пожалуйста?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вижу что проблема в 29 строке кода, пишет что `Объект 'str' не имеет атрибута 'replace'`, я не совсем понимаю, почему так? Код и вывод с консоли привел ниже

```
import os
import time

# Откуда копируем
source = ['D:\Miscellanea\Backup']
# Куда копируем
target_dir = 'D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive'


# Создание названия папки с сохраненым архивом резервных данных, в формате: 
# %Месяц%День%Год
today = target_dir + os.sep + time.strftime('%m.%d.%Y')
# Создание имени zip-архива в формате: %Час%Минута
now = time.strftime('%H.%M')


# Просим пользователя ввести комментарий к архиву
comment = input('Введите комментарий: ')
# Если введеный текст не позволителен для имени файла в ОС, то...
if len(comment) == 0:
    # Прописывем путь сохранения архива, присваиваем имя архиву
    target = today + os.sep + now + '.zip'
    # D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive\\%H.%M.zip
    # %H.%M.zip
else:
    # Меняем все пробелы на знак "_" и
    # прописывем путь сохранения архива, присваиваем имя архиву
    target = today + os.sep + now + '_' + \
    comment.replaсe(' ', '_') + '.zip'
    

# Если указанный путь существует то...
if not os.path.exists(today):
    # Создать папку с именем равным значению переменной today
    os.mkdir(today)


print('Происходит процесс архивации резервных данных, пожалуйста подождите...')


# В zip_command передается "D:\Miscellanea\Backup Archive\\%H.%M.zip" 
# "D:\Miscellanea\Backup"
zip_command = 'zip -qr "{0}" {1}'.format(target, ' '.join(source))


# Если запуск команды zip_command возможен(возращает 0), то... 
if os.system(zip_command) == 0:
    # Вывести оповещение
    print('Архив резервных копий успешно создан в', target)
else:
    # Вывести оповещение
    print('Создание архива резервных копий НЕ УДАЛАСЬ')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас русская буква `с` в слове `replace` в строке `comment.replaсe(' ', '_') + '.zip'`, замените её на латинскую. Проверка:

```
[hex(ord(ch)) for ch in 'replaсe']

['0x72', '0x65', '0x70', '0x6c', '0x61', '0x441', '0x65']
                                          ^^^^^
```

Comment: блин не успел написать

Comment: @Danis А сколько раз я не успевал за вами написать! )

Comment: сколько раз я вас обижал и даже не знал об этом. простите меня

Comment: @CrazyElf Не думал что да такого дойдет, теперь буду внимательнее, спасибо)

Comment: @Danis Взаимно! Хотя это всё и оффтопик ))

Comment: @АнатолийМихеенко В моей 25-летней практике программирования чего только не бывало, это чуть не самое первое что встречалось ещё давно - путаница в одинаково пишущихся буквах

Comment: сколько вам лет? вам больше 35?

Comment: @Danis Да, в 1.4 раза %)

Comment: вы старше на два года. моего отца